# How to undock WinForms form designer in Visual Studio?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

How can i undock the WinForms form design in Visual Studio (so that it's not embedded in a tab, or encased in a *"penalty box"*) so that it reacts similar to how Delphi-7 could undock the form?

e.g. This is what i have:

[image]

**Note:** The yellow highlight indicating the area of the form visible in the designer, red indicating the area of the form obscured by the *penalty box*.

This is what i want:

[image]

**Note:** A free-floating designable form, [circa 2003](http://www.econtrol.ru/images/form_design_big.jpg).

Comment: How is this a Delphi 7 question?

Comment: @KenWhite i know, i know - it's a stretch. But Delphi 7 was the last Delphi to come with the floating form designer. i really didn't imagine people who watch Delphi would be watching `delphi-7`.

Comment: Ian, if the question has zero to do with Delphi at all (since your question is about VS and not RAD Studio). any Delphi tag is wrong. The text of your question doesn't even mention Delphi, and neither do the images.

Comment: @KenWhite Shall i edit the question to explicitly state that the question's included link points to, and the ideal behavior is already implemented in, Delphi 7?

Comment: Um, no. I'd like you to remove the Delphi tag, because the question has nothing to do with Delphi. I figured since you're not new here, you could figure out why yourself; I didn't intend to get into an argument about it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Click-and-hold on its tab, and drag it.

Is that what you’re looking for?

EDIT:
Here's an Alt+PrtScrn:
[image]

**Edit**: Here's a snipping tool screenshot:

[image]

Comment: My form is still stuck inside a "penalty box".

Comment: @IanBoyd Perhaps you’re dropping it on one of the options in the middle of the screen (when dragging) – drop it somewhere else. I just tried it and it works fine. In fact, I stretched it to full-screen, with no unwanted additions (except a minimal amount on the top and left.)

Comment: i added a screenshot of what i see, which looks similar to what you see - the form is stuck inside a form. (See your screenshot's `Form1.cs [Design]*` title bar of the window surrounding your window)